# Why doesn't the option "User:roles"  show in "Contextual Filter"?

Tags: views

I can't see the option "User: roles" in the contextual filter, and when I select "Relationships" I don't see "User Roles".  What happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a relationship "Content:author"; then, the "User:role" filter will appear in "Filter criteria."

Comment: In the relationship "Content:author", not appears FILTER CRITERIA "User: role".  I will edit my question

Comment: It's for  Views 7.x-3.3 you can add (author)User:Role filter to filter the content by its authors role, its not a contextual filter but an ordinary one. It appears after adding "Content:author" relationship

Comment: Your answer is very useful for me.  Thanks very much.